# How to convert dataframe from wide to long and fill new rows of non-ID and not-to-be-gathered columns with NA

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that I want to convert from wide to long with 9 columns. 3 columns are ID columns, 2 columns are to be gathered, and the last 4 columns are not to be gathered and they are not ID, meaning when new rows are added to these 4 columns, I don't want the values in them to be repeated, I want the new rows filled with NA.

I've managed with an ugly solution, but I wondered if anyone could think of a more systematic and elegant one.

My crappy-dirty solution was to separate the 4 columns from the original data set and make it a new dataset. And solely because I know I will end up with only 2 rows per individual, I can insert a new row every 2 rows filled with NA, and then cbind this "filled" dataframe back to the original.
But that only works easily because I have a systematic dataset with all individuals having exactly 2 rows well organized. If the dataset was a bit more chaotic, that wouldn't be as easy.

So, the original dataframe looks like that:
[original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx0Lb.png)

I want that:
[long df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icYAW.png)

The link to the example csv file is here:[github repository](https://github.com/CWR-05/Data_wrangling_StackOverflow)

and that's my ugly solution:

```
#load data
df<- read.csv("example_dataset_20231017.csv")

#separate ID columns and columns to gather into a core dataframe, and columns that are neither ID or to be gathered into a separate df
core<- df %>%
  dplyr::select(AnimalID, datein, dateout, area, species) %>% #select columns
  gather(date_t, date, datein:dateout, factor_key = TRUE) %>% #wide o long
  arrange(AnimalID) #re-order columns

sub<- df %>%
  arrange(AnimalID) %>% #re-arrange columns to match core df
  dplyr::select(event, season, group_y, group) %>% #select columns
  group_by(grp = (row_number() - 1)) %>%  #group by row number
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, .before = 0)) %>%  #add row BEFORE each row of df
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-grp) #remove the grp column

#bind the 2 df together
df.long<- cbind(core, sub)
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to do that elegantly and systematically, in a way that would work for any dataframe? (ideally with tidyverse, but I'd take any simple, short and pretty code ;) )

Comment: Hi Chloe, welcome! Not to be a party pooper, but why would you want it to be in the second format? It's full of NAs, and you're losing information along with it

Answer (score 2):

Storing data in this format is almost certainly a bad idea, because in essence you're just adding a bunch of NAs to the data, making it harder to use. Even if you were to not add all of the NAs (as I did in my answer below), you're still repeating every value in a bunch of columns twice. I would strongly reconsider what you're doing before using this, and ask yourself if there's a better, [tidier](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) way of doing what you're trying to do (because there almost certainly is).

That said, if you're just asking *if* it can be done- yes, it can be done this way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(starts_with("date"), values_to = "date") |> # make the data longer (equivalent to gather (tidyr recommends using pivot_longer over gather now))
  mutate(across(event:group, ~ ifelse(name == "dateout", NA, .))) |> # for the columns event to group, if the name for our row of lengthened data is "dateout", then make the value NA, else don't change it
  select(AnimalID, date, area:group) # reorder the columns
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 100 × 8
   AnimalID  date        area species event season group_y group
   <chr>     <date>     <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>
 1 An2001137 2020-07-11     2 mic         0 s      g7      g7_s 
 2 An2001137 2022-10-31     2 mic        NA NA     NA      NA   
 3 An1801179 2018-08-19     1 mic         1 s      g7      g7_s 
 4 An1801179 2022-10-31     1 mic        NA NA     NA      NA   
 5 An1501164 2015-07-27     1 mic         0 s      g7      g7_s 
 6 An1501164 2022-10-31     1 mic        NA NA     NA      NA   
 7 An1501727 2015-08-23     1 mon         0 ns     g5      g5_ns
 8 An1501727 2020-03-31     1 mon        NA NA     NA      NA   
 9 An0900050 2009-07-18     1 mic         0 s      g7      g7_s 
10 An0900050 2022-08-25     1 mic        NA NA     NA      NA   
# ℹ 90 more rows
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I know exactly what I'm doing. It's only step 1 in a (much) longer exercise of data wrangling. In the end, each individual will have 1 entry per year of presence, and NAs will be filled with the right data. Your code is great though, short and sweet! (just need the NAs on datein not dateout easy to change). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a job for reshape or gather because the data assigned to datein is the same as the data for dateout in your original dataframe. Thus, whatever function you run over this, it would not know why datein and dateout are related to different datacolumns. So your approach was basically right, that is to create a new dataframe where empty data is assigned to datein. Here is a somewhat simpler solution with tidyverse:

```
#package
library("tidyverse")

#1 read data
df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CWR-05/Data_wrangling_StackOverflow/main/example_dataset_20231017.csv")

#2 separate data & rename common column
datein <- df %>% select(AnimalID, date=datein)
dateout <- df %>% select(-datein, date=dateout)

#3 merge data
result <- bind_rows(datein, dateout)

#4 you might want to sort it like this
result <- result %>% arrange(AnimalID, date)
```

Comment: on the contrary, i'd say gather (or pivot_longer) is the function for this. Debatable in this case but [in general it's a bad idea to repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Thank you. That's shorter than mine. However, I'm thinking just like my solution, yours will also quickly be complicated to implement, if the dataset is less systematic, with more than 2 dates per individuals (aka more than 2 columns to gather), or if individuals have different amount of data. Cheers